# How to select columns with equal or more than 2 unique values while ignoring NA and blank?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

My dataframe looks similar to this:

```
 df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               color = c(NA, "black", "black", NA, "brown"),
              animal = c("dog", "", "", "", "")
               owner = c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", NA))
```

| ID | color | animal | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | dog | YES |
| 2 | black |  | NO |
| 3 | black |  | NO |
| 4 | NA |  | YES |
| 5 | brown |  | NA |

I would like to retrieve the column names of all columns with more than 2 unique values while ignoring NA and blanks/empty strings in this calculation.

My solution so far:

```
df_col <- df %>% 
        select_if(function(col) length(unique(na.omit(col)))>1)

df_col <- colnames(df_col)
```

But I have noticed that na.omit() won't help, since it deletes the whole row.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `n_distinct`, which also have `na.rm` argument, The `_if/_at/_all` are deprecated in favor of `across/where`.  The empty strings (`''`) can be checked with `nzchar` which returns a TRUE only if it is non-empty, thus subset the elements of the columns with `nzchar` and then apply `n_distinct` column wise and create the condition to `select` only those columns and then get the `names`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(~ n_distinct(.x[nzchar(.x)], na.rm = TRUE) > 1)) %>%
     names
```

-output

```
[1] "ID"    "color" "owner"
```

---

An option is also to convert the `""` to `NA` (`na_if`), perhaps it may be slightly compact

```
df %>% 
  select(where(~ n_distinct(na_if(.x, ""), na.rm = TRUE) > 1)) %>% 
  names
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do replace values with "" with NA (`na_if`), and then use `lengths` to count the number of unique values. Use `names` and `which` to get the vector of names that have more than two values.

```r
names(which(lengths(lapply(na_if(df, ""), \(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)]))) >= 2))
[1] "ID"    "color" "owner"
```

Combining with `n_distinct`:

```r
colnames(df)[lapply(na_if(df, ""), n_distinct, na.rm = T) >= 2]
[1] "ID"    "color" "owner"
```